# How do i fix my reconnect code for AWS IOT

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mqtt, reconnect

```
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import os
import socket
import ssl

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags,rc):
    print("Connection returned result: " +str(rc) )
mqttc = paho.Client()
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect

awshost = "azl4495ut899m-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
awsport = 8883
clientId = "myThingName"
thingName = "myThingName"
caPath = "/home/pi/AWSIoT/root-ca.pem"
certPath = "/home/pi/AWSIoT/certificate.pem.crt"
keyPath = "/home/pi/AWSIoT/private.pem.key"

mqttc.tls_set(caPath, certfile=certPath, 
keyfile=keyPath, 
cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, 
tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)

mqttc.connect(awshost, awsport)
mqttc.loop_forever()
while True:
        if mqttc.connect(awshost, awsport)== 0:
            mqttc.connect(awshost, awsport)
            print("Connected")
            time.sleep(45)
            mqttc.disconnect(awshost,awsport)
            print("Disconnected")
        if mqttc.connect(awshost, awsport) != 0:
            mqttc.reconnect(awshost,awsport)
            print("reconnecting")
```

Here is the Error when i lose internet connection:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/AWSIoT/awsiotcore2.1", line 
44, in <module>
if mqttc.connect(awshost, awsport) != 0:
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 914, in 
connect
return self.reconnect()
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1044, 
in reconnect
sock = self._create_socket_connection()
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3685, 
in _create_socket_connection
return socket.create_connection(addr, 
timeout=self._connect_timeout, 
source_address=source)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 
694, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, 
SOCK_STREAM):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 
733, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 
family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary 
failure in name resolution
```

if I dont not add the while loop with disconnects I lose connection to AWS in 6
minutes and have to manually reconnect.
This loop is the only way I can stay
connected to AWS. If someone could tell me
why aws disconnects me every 6 mins without
the stupid disconnect loop please let me
know

**SOLUTION**

```
while True:  
   mqttc.on_connect=on_connect
   print("Connected")
   time.sleep(45)
   mqttc.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
try:
    mqttc.connect(awshost,awsport)
except Exception:
    print("Error Connecting")
    pass
```

Comment: Please reformat your code (the positioning of line breaks is important) and show the code that is not working clearly (currently it looks like `mqttc.loop_forever()` will never be called due to the `while True:` so you have no [network loop](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#network-loop)). The code shown appears to be manually disconnecting every 45 seconds?

Comment: Yes at the bottom i explain why i manually disconnect

Comment: If i completely take out the while loop it works, but only for 6 minutes, if you can fix that problem then i wont need the while loop

Comment: It looks like there is an [open issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/529) for this (or a very similar problem). The issue is [here](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/9782ab81fe7ee3a05e74c7f3e1d03d5611ea4be4/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L1743) `gaierror` is an `OSError` so is not caught. You could surround the `mqttc.loop_forever()`  with `while True:` and `try`/`catch` but may also want to look at why the DNS query is failing.

Comment: Using the try/catch worked.

Comment: while True:  
    mqttc.on_connect=on_connect
    print("Connected")
    time.sleep(45)
    mqttc.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
    try:
        mqttc.connect(awshost,awsport)
    except Exception:
        print("Error Connecting")
        pass

Comment: Ill add that to my post as a fix to my problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Ceotheis Consider post your solution in answer to show this question has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:  
   mqttc.on_connect=on_connect
   print("Connected")
   time.sleep(45)
   mqttc.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
try:
   mqttc.connect(awshost,awsport)
 except Exception:
   print("Error Connecting")
   pass
```

Comment: You still need a [network loop](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#network-loop).

Comment: It still connects to the network with that loop. What would I need to add?

Comment: Does 'on_connect' get called? (this is done in the network loop). `connect` returns when the network connection is up but before the initial CONNACK from the MQTT broker is processed. You may get away with this if just publishing at QOS0 but are still likely to have issues (e.g. keepalives not being sent).

Comment: So oddly enough it connects, but doesn't print the statement within in the function. Where would I add the loop? Would I just use loop.start() or loop.forever()

Comment: `on_connect` is only called when the CONNACK packet is received and that is processed in the network loop (as mentioned `connect()` returns before that point). `loop_forever` is fine - just make sure its within the `try`/`catch` (usually immediately after `connect`).